# See all result of a query

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I do a query and i have 5000 registers but select2 only show me 3278, why?
how can I fix it?

I try it with

```
$('select').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: 20 // at least 20 results must be displayed
});
```

Comment: Do you mean you have 5000 option nodes in the select?

Comment: yes, the select has all the codes of the student of my university

Answer (score 0):

This must be some browser limitation or something in your code.

I tested this with chrome and it shows all 5000.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7a6ecrt2/1/

**Markup:**

```
<select id="mySelect">
</select>
```

**Code**

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
x.options.length = 5000;
var i = 5000;
while (i) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = "fred" + i;
  option.value = "freddy" + i;
  x[i] = option;
  i--;
}
alert(x.options.length);
$('#mySelect').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: 20 // at least 20 results must be displayed
});
```